# Flask - How to store logs and add additional information

Tags: python, logging, web-applications, flask, flask-login

I would like to store "werkzeug" output in a file (or create a similar log file)  and add additional data to each line of log. (For example a value for the username if the value is known in the session)

How to proceed ? I would like the user to be "unknown" if the username is not known in the session.

Is it possible to define everything before doing app.run() ?
(Because I did ran into 'working outside of request context' errors when trying to use the session object before app.run)

```
class UserIDFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """
    from flask import session
    def filter(self, record):
        username = session.get('username','unknown')
        record.user_id = username
        return True


logFormatStr = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='output.log',format = logFormatStr, level=logging.DEBUG)
app.run(debug=True)
```

My question about app.run was understanding how the program will be able to get access to the user value stored in the session. (I thought maybe I have to fire up "app.run" before defining the logging.)

The best answer for me would be a Hello World example with the username stored in the session and with a log file (similar to werkzeug) with that information added.

Answer (score 4):

There are several questions in your question.

for the first one, you can check the documentation here: [Logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/quickstart/#logging) and [Logging to a File](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file).

for the second one, you can use `session.get('someone', 'unknown')`, return 'unknown' if 'someone' is not in the session, else it just returns the value.

for the last one. `app.run()` is used to fire up a development server, what do you mean by `define everything before doing app.run()`. And only the error may not very helpful, show some code and paste the full error log.

A basic example for how to log in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, session

import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    user_name = session.get('Hello, world', 'unknown')
    app.logger.debug('Say somethind here'.format(
        user_name, extra={'username': user_name}))
    return 'Hello, {0}.'.format(user_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_handler = FileHandler('app.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(
        Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(username)s: %(message)s'))
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and when you run the app, you'll find a `app.log` file in the same directory, the content is:

```
2016-01-07 20:19:09,636 DEBUG unknown: say something here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already checked the documentation but I can't figure out how to make it work without "basicConfig" or when adding something in the format string. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I just want to add a username (the one defined in the session variable) in the log and I would like to understand how to. When I do without basicConfig I have nothing in my log file.

Comment: @DavidK Updated the answer, is that you want?

Comment: Thanks, I would like the username for each line (inside) of '%(asctime)s %user (levelname)s: %(message)s' and unknow when not known.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no log format to add a user name in each log, you need to add it by hand. What do you mean by `unknow when not known`, in my example, it is 'unknown' when the user isn't in the session.

Comment: I've seen there were solutions with loggerAdapter or logfilter but I was not able to make it work. Are you aware of these possibilities ? Yes, 'unknow' when not in the session.

Comment: @DavidK Updated my answer, have a try ;)

Comment: Thanks. That's not exactly what I want. I want the same output that in the cli (werkzeug) with the username added. (without doing anything else than modifying the value of username in the session)

Comment: I think my question is close to this one but I can't have it working : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317993/how-to-add-custom-parameter-into-python-logging-formatter